# create keras input layers using the functional api through a for loop?

Tags: python, keras

Suppose for a moment that I need to dynamically generate a keras model specific to a user. Each user can have a variable number of categorical inputs, but once you know the number of categorical inputs it would be trivial to hand build a model.

I want to write a function that given a list of the cardinality of each of the categorical variables will return an appropriate model. My first stab at the problem produced the following solution, but it just doesn't seem right to execute a string(s) like this.

```py
from keras.layers import Dense,Embedding,Input,Flatten,Add
from keras.models import Model

def build_model(input_cardinalities,num_outputs):
    layers = []
    inputs = []
    for i,cardinality in enumerate(input_cardinalities):
        exec("input{0} = Input(shape=[1], name='input{0}')".format(i))
        exec("embedding{0} =  Embedding({1}, 20, name='embedding{0}')(input{0})".format(i,cardinality))
        exec("vec{0} = Flatten(name='flatten{0}')(embedding{0})".format(i))
        exec("layers.append(vec{0})".format(i))
        exec("inputs.append(input{0})".format(i))
    context_layer = Add(layers)
    dense1 = Dense(50, name='Dense1',activation='relu')(context_layer)
    dense2 = Dense(num_outputs, name='Output', activation='softmax')(dense1)
    model = Model(inputs,dense2)
    model.compile('sgd','categorical_crossentropy')
    return model
```

I just don't feel comfortable executing strings like this, but it is the only way that I can think of to do what I want. I just feel like there should be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual need to use `exec` at all, you are building one input/embedding at a time, then storing them into lists. That is the correct way to do it, and it does not require `exec`.

```
def build_model(input_cardinalities,num_outputs):
    layers = []
    inputs = []
    for i,cardinality in enumerate(input_cardinalities):
        input = Input(shape=[1], name='input{0}'.format(i))
        embedding =  Embedding(cardinality, 20, name='embedding{0}'.format(i))
        vec = Flatten(name='flatten{0}'.format(i))(embedding)
        layers.append(vec)
        inputs.append(input)
    context_layer = Add()(layers)
    dense1 = Dense(50, name='Dense1',activation='relu')(context_layer)
    dense2 = Dense(num_outputs, name='Output', activation='softmax')(dense1)
    model = Model(inputs,dense2)
    model.compile('sgd','categorical_crossentropy')
    return model
```

Also note I corrected the `Add()(layers)` call.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.

Comment: if ```input_cardinalities``` is not fixed, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, where I wanted to instantiate multiple input layers using a for loop. First I tried to reproduce the above, and just completing the above answers for comprehensiveness (and printing model summary).

```py
from keras.layers import Dense,Embedding,Input,Flatten,Add
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

def build_model(input_cardinalities,num_outputs):
    layers = []
    inputs = []
    for i,cardinality in enumerate(input_cardinalities):
        input = Input(shape=[1], name='input{0}'.format(i))
        embedding =  Embedding(cardinality, 20, name='embedding{0}'.format(i))(input)
        vec = Flatten(name='flatten{0}'.format(i))(embedding)
        layers.append(vec)
        inputs.append(input)
    context_layer = Add(name='context')(layers)
    dense1 = Dense(50, name='Dense1',activation='relu')(context_layer)
    dense2 = Dense(num_outputs, name='Output', activation='softmax')(dense1)
    model = Model(inputs,dense2)
    model.compile('sgd','categorical_crossentropy')
    return model
```

Then building the model like

```py
input_cardinalities = [1,2,3]
num_outputs = 6
model = build_model(input_cardinalities, num_outputs)
model.summary()
plot_model(model, 'model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

and the output looks like this

```
Model: "model_14"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input0 (InputLayer)             [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input1 (InputLayer)             [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input2 (InputLayer)             [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding0 (Embedding)          (None, 1, 20)        20          input0[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding1 (Embedding)          (None, 1, 20)        40          input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding2 (Embedding)          (None, 1, 20)        60          input2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten0 (Flatten)              (None, 20)           0           embedding0[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten1 (Flatten)              (None, 20)           0           embedding1[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten2 (Flatten)              (None, 20)           0           embedding2[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
context (Add)                   (None, 20)           0           flatten0[0][0]                   
                                                                 flatten1[0][0]                   
                                                                 flatten2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Dense1 (Dense)                  (None, 50)           1050        context[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Output (Dense)                  (None, 6)            306         Dense1[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,476
Trainable params: 1,476
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

and for better visualization see
[a plot_model() return of this model here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf792.png)

Answer (score 0):

there is a `(input)` missing at the end of:

```
embedding =  Embedding(cardinality, 20, name='embedding{0}'.format(i))(input)
```